# LWC Controller creates record with combo box but not lookup

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-inputfield

So I have an LWC component. I've put a child component lookup input and 3 other number and text input fields in a repeating section on HTML, that works great.

```
<div class="slds-col margin-horizontal">
    <c-lwc-lookup-component 
    name="indicator"
    field-label="Indicator"
    child-object-api-name="M_E_Metric__c"
    target-field-api-name="Indicator__c"
    value={v.indicator}
    required="false"
    add-to-recent="false"
    onvalueselected={handleSelectedLookup}
    onchange={handleChange}
    data-index={index}>
</c-lwc-lookup-component>
</div>
```

However when I save the record on in the JS controller handSave method, it doesn't work for some reason. The console logs so the values as expected but no feedback after hitting the save button

```
for(let rowIndex in this.metricList) {
        console.log('step 1.1');
        fields[INDICATOR_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.metricList[rowIndex].indicator;
        console.log('indicator field' + this.metricList[rowIndex].indicator);
        fields[ASPECT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.metricList[rowIndex].aspect;
        console.log('indicator field' + this.metricList[rowIndex].aspect);
        fields[TARGET_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.metricList[rowIndex].target;
        console.log('indicator field' + this.metricList[rowIndex].target);
        fields[BASELINE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.metricList[rowIndex].baseline;
        console.log('indicator field' + this.metricList[rowIndex].baseline);
        fields[APPLICATION_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
        console.log('indicator field' + this.recordId);
        console.log('indicator field' + fields);

        //console.log('fields' + fields);
        const recordInput = { apiName: METRIC_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields};
        //console.log('recordInput' + recordInput);
        createRecord(recordInput)
```

Even stranger, when I change the child component to hard coded values in combobox, it works

```
<div class="slds-col margin-horizontal">
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="indicator"
                            label="Indicator"
                            value={v.indicator}
                            placeholder="Select Indicator"
                            options={indicator_options}
                            onchange={handleChange}
                            data-index={index}>
                        </lightning-combobox>  
                    </div>
```

In the console, it's exactly the same results for the indicator field value and I'm completely stumped why it's not working for the child lookup component but working with combobox. Any ideas?